# Disable the date field

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular js, so my requirement is when I add an item for the first item to the cart checkbox will be enabled and date field will be editable mode and when I try to add the item for second-time date field should be non-editable this I am doing using if condition. So how can I make date field non-editable in if condition?

I need to add date non-editable in if condition below.

```
if($scope.supplierChooserObject.commodityCode != "5215"){
    $scope.isLimitOrderObject.showCheckbox = false;
    isLimitOrderObject=false;        
}else{
    $scope.isLimitOrderObject.showCheckbox = true;
    isLimitOrderObject=true;
}
```

```html
<li class="adhoc-form-end-date adhoc-form-input-section">
    <field class="col-xs-12" ng-model="endDateObject2" editable="true">
    </field>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you need to set <field> to be editable == true on a specific condition ?

Comment: Could you please explain what these two are doing : $scope.isLimitOrderObject , isLimitOrderObject=false;

Comment: yes i need to set editable == false on specific condition

Comment: islimitorderobject this holds state of requisition.

Comment: By mistake i added wrong script i have edited it again.

Comment: What happens if you set editable = true  OR false? That is the all you want?

Comment: editable == false making that field disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting **editable** to a variable will solve your problem.

> Like this : editable="isLimitOrderObject.showCheckboxz"

Whole code :

```
if($scope.supplierChooserObject.commodityCode != "5215"){
    $scope.isLimitOrderObject.showCheckbox = false;
    isLimitOrderObject=false;

}else{
    $scope.isLimitOrderObject.showCheckbox = true;
    isLimitOrderObject=true;
}
<li class="adhoc-form-end-date adhoc-form-input-section">
    <field class="col-xs-12" ng-model="endDateObject2" editable="isLimitOrderObject.showCheckboxz"></field>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi rahim..it works but  date i can see as normal text format like without box around.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/readonly-state/   

can i get something like this?

Comment: Could you please generate a code pen for your code?
Also if this answer helped you please select this answer.

Comment: its difficult to generate the code pen since we are using inbuilt UIField for date.